# Pandas adding header (indices) to csv file even though index=False

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, csv

I'm just trying to do some filtering on an excel file and convert it to csv, but for some reason the output csv has the first row consisting of the column indices and I can't fix it.

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from FileHandler import select_save_file
def filter_by_action(input_file): 
    # Read the Excel file
    excel_file_path = input_file
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, header=None)



    # Filter rows where column C (index 2) equals '1'
    filtered_df = df[df[2].isin([1,3,5])]
    
    
    print(filtered_df)


    
    csv_file_path = select_save_file("csv")
    if not csv_file_path:
        return
    
    # Save the filtered data to a CSV file with UTF-8 encoding
    filtered_df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    print(f"Filtered data saved to: {csv_file_path}")
```

And here is what gets printed from filtered_df (roughly)

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6         7              8         9   ...  76 77
0  IMM   1   1 NaN   0   0 NaN  IM - 118  Artikelnummer  IM - 118  ... NaN  0
```

Am I missing something or should this not just return a csv file with only the row after the zero (i.e IMM,1,1,NaN and so on)? Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: _And here is what gets printed from filtered_df_ Why do you expect that writing a csv file with no header would have any effect on the dataframe?  Surely you should be checking **the csv file** to see that it has no header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the first row of the printed output, you might have to set `header=None` in the `to_csv` function.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html